# Why does my list of Realm objects loaded into FlatList using realm-react only render if I use the spread operator?

Tags: react-native, realm

```
import React from "react"
import { initialWindowMetrics, SafeAreaProvider } from "react-native-safe-area-context"
import {FlatList, SafeAreaView, Text, View, } from "react-native";
import {colors} from "./theme";
import {LocationRealm} from "./realm/models/LocationRealm";
import RealmContext from './realm/AppRealm';

const { RealmProvider, useQuery } = RealmContext;

function App() {
    return <RealmProvider>
        <SafeAreaProvider initialMetrics={initialWindowMetrics}>
            <LocationsView/>
        </SafeAreaProvider>
    </RealmProvider>
}

export const LocationsView = () => {

    const locations = useQuery(LocationRealm)

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1, height: "100%"}}>
            <FlatList
                data={[...locations]} // <--- working (shows on UI)
                // data={locations} // <-- not working (empty list)
                keyExtractor={ (item, index) => `${item.id}` }
                renderItem={({item}) => {
                    {console.log(item)}
                    return <View style={{height: 100, backgroundColor: colors.tint}}>
                        <Text>{item.locationName}</Text>
                    </View>
                }}
            />
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
}

export default App
```

---

```
import Realm from "realm";

export class LocationRealm extends Realm.Object<LocationRealm> {

    id!: string;
    locationName!: string;

    static generate(index: number, name: String) {
        return {
            id: `${Math.random()}`,
            locationName: name,
        }
    }

    static schema: Realm.ObjectSchema = {
        name: "LocationRealm",
        primaryKey: "id",
        properties: {
            id: "string",
            locationName: "string",
        }
    }

}
```

The above code is only rendering LocationRealm objects into the UI from the Realm Database when using `[...locations]` instead of just `locations`. In all the demos and example projects I have seen, the spread operator was not needed. I am not getting any error messages or crashes, just an empty FlatList.

```
"@realm/react": "^0.4.3"

"realm": "^11.4.0"
```

Comment: SO is a terrible interactive debugger and really not the best place to determine why something 'works' or 'doesn't work' without specific debuting details. What does 'doesn't work' mean? What are you doing with `data` that indicates it doesn't work? Is there an error? A crash? Something else? What is `locations in the Realm Database`? Where are you getting that data? Please take a moment and review [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/5404

The issue is that FlatList from react-native introduced a guard in the _getItemCount function in RN 0.71.2.  Here is the commit:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/d574ea3526e713eae2c6e20c7a68fa66ff4ad7d2

useQuery returns an object of type Realm.Results, which fails the Array.isArray() guard.

You can use patch-package to remove the guard from the FlatList.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue here, ignore that chump above.

Strangely - if you use locations.map() you'll be able to render using the same data set, but FlatList returns an empty UI.

If you use the underlying VirtualizedList component and pass data={locations} you'll also be able to render.

There must be something with the FlatList component itself that's having issues with the realm results from useQuery.